# Spring Boot error handling in app combining MVC and rest api

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am currently trying to figure out the best way to handle errors in a spring boot app.
Assume that the app consists of thymeleaf templates served on paths starting with /admin, and a REST API served on other URIs.

My project currently has the following configuration:

- Thymeleaf error templates located at /src/main/resources/templates/error/{id}.html, defined for errors 400, 401, 403, 404, 500.
- Default thymeleaf error template /src/main/resources/templates/error.html
- HttpSecurity configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    (...)
    http
        .anonymous();
    http
        .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authException) -> response.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.getReasonPhrase()))
            .accessDeniedHandler(new AccessDeniedHandlerImpl());
    (...)
}
```

- Exception Handlers for both rest and MVC:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlers {

    private final BasicErrorController basicErrorController;

    public ExceptionHandlers(BasicErrorController basicErrorController) {
        this.basicErrorController = basicErrorController;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public Object handleAllExceptions(Exception e, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        return handle(e, request, response, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(EntityNotFoundException.class)
    public Object handleEntityNotFoundException(EntityNotFoundException e, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        return handle(e, request, response, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, I18nCodes.ENTITY_NOT_FOUND);
    }

    /**
     * We exclude all exceptions deriving from {@link AccessDeniedException} from custom exception handling.
     */
    @ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class)
    public Object handleAccessDeniedException(AccessDeniedException e, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        throw e;
    }

    /**
     * We exclude all exceptions deriving from {@link AppBaseException} from custom exception handling.
     */
    @ExceptionHandler(AppBaseException.class)
    public Object handleAppBaseException(AppBaseException e, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        throw e;
    }

    private Object handle(Exception e, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, HttpStatus status) {
        return handle(e, request, response, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, I18nCodes.getCodeByStatus(status));
    }

    private Object handle(Exception e, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, HttpStatus status, String message) {
        String header = request.getHeader("Accept");
        if (header != null && header.contains("text/html")) {
            setErrorCode(request, response, status);
            return basicErrorController.errorHtml(request, response);
        }
        return createJsonResponse(message, status, request.getRequestURI());
    }

    private ResponseEntity<ErrorResponseDTO> createJsonResponse(String message, HttpStatus status, String path) {
        ErrorResponseDTO errorResponseDTO = new ErrorResponseDTO()
                .setTimestamp(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setStatus(status.value())
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPath(path)
                .setError(status.name().toLowerCase());
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        return ResponseEntity.status(status).headers(httpHeaders).body(errorResponseDTO);
    }


    private void setErrorCode(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, HttpStatus httpStatus) {
        request.setAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE, httpStatus.value());
        response.setStatus(httpStatus.value());
    }

}
```

Without the Exception handlers everything works about as expected, I get 401 error when I am not authenticated, and 403 when authenticated but lacking authorities. My custom exceptions are correctly mapped according to their message and Status defined in @ResponseStatus eg:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public class AccountInfoException extends AppBaseException {
    protected AccountInfoException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    protected AccountInfoException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

    public static AccountInfoException emailAlreadyExists() {
        return new AccountInfoException(I18nCodes.EMAIL_EXIST);
    }

    public static AccountInfoException accountNotFound() {
        return new AccountInfoException(I18nCodes.ACCOUNT_NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

Will map to status 400 with one of two messages I18nCodes.EMAIL_EXIST or I18nCodes.ACCOUNT_NOT_FOUND.

I arrive on the correct thymeleaf error page depending on the status code - life is perfect.

The issue comes with the requirement of handling all other exceptions. It's not a possibility to let an unexpected error to the client. So for that I've defined an exception handler handing Exception, to return a generic 500 message. This breaks everything. I'm unable to access the Status codes of my custom exceptions
Authentication entry point and access denied handler are both ignored, and both cases of being not authenticated and having insufficient authority are handles in the same exception(AccessDeniedException). I also lose default mappings for some exceptions eg. org.springframework.security.authentication.LockedException returns status 401.

My temporary workaround was to handle all exceptions, and to create methods handling exceptions that I want to ignore and just rethrow the exception. I feel like the best thing I could do is remove all exception handlers and repack all container exceptions to my own custom exceptions, only issue is that there doesn't seem to be a way to do it.

I'm looking for a more permanent solution - what would be the best approach?